# Do the digits(after comma) of the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$ contain all natural numbers without jumping order?

Tags: irrational-numbers

If we mention about $\sqrt{2}=1.41421356$ It contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,41,414,4142,41421 But it does not contain 4121
$\sqrt(2)$ does not contain repetitive patterns and it is not transcendental number(0,10010001...)(which contains only specific digits) and I tried to prove that after comma after some point $\sqrt(2)$ can not contain repetitive natural number with specific distance such as(3165,3,3165,7,3165,9,3165,3,..)and I tried to prove that after comma at some specific point some digit can not be eliminated such as 3 or 2 are possible but others not(3264,3,2563,2,3564,3,...).if these two sentences are proved.İt can prove that $\sqrt(2)$ contains all natural numbers.In fact I tried to prove that impossibility of solving this problem(I think that in math there can be propositions which can be true or false but proving is impossible.)

Comment: This is not clear.  If you are asking whether or not the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ contains every natural number then I don't believe this is known (though it is widely believed).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @lulu In fact this is unknown and the only evidence for the normality of $\sqrt{2}$ is the behaviour of the calculated digits and the "argument" that almost all real numbers are normal , so there is no reason that $\sqrt{2}$ is not.

Comment: @Peter do we know of any not-normal irrational numbers that weren't specifically constructed as such?

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Depends on what you count as "specifically constructed". For example, [Liouville's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html) is extremely non-normal, but its lack of normality is not the main point of the construction. AFAIR what is _really_ in short supply are known _normal_ numbers that are not constructed with the specific purpose of being normal.